# If $|G_1|=|G_2|<\infty$ and $|G_1'|<|G_2'|$, then $|Z(G_1)|\geq |Z(G_2)|$? where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, conjectures

We know that $G'$ characterization how ``abelian'' of a group
because we have a theorem: if $G'=\{e\}$, then $G$ is abelian.

I have a conjecture.

If there are two finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, 
$|G_1|=|G_2|$ and $|G_1'|< |G_2'|$,
where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$,
does it imply that $|Z(G_1)|\geq |Z(G_2)|$?

Or find a counterexample, is there an example satisfing $|G_1|=|G_2|<\infty$, $|G_1'|< |G_2'|$
and $|Z(G_1)|< |Z(G_2)|$?

This conjecture is true for $|G|\leq 30$ by verify manually myself and this [website](http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/groups/groups.html).

**Remarks** There is a similar *theorem*:
if $\text{inn }G=\{e\}$, 
then $G$ is abelian,
where $\text{inn }G$ is the group of inner automorphism on $G$.

If there are two finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, 
$|G_1|=|G_2|$ and $|\text{inn }G_1|< |\text{inn }G_2|$,
which imply that $|Z(G_1)|> |Z(G_2)|$ 
because $G/Z(G)\cong \text{inn }G$.

Comment: I can think of counterexamples of order $72$ ($G_1$ with $|G_1'|= 9$, $|Z(G_1)|=1$, $G_2$ with $|G_2'|=18$, $|Z(G_2)|=2$), but there might be smaller examples.

Comment: @DerekHolt What are the groups $G_1$ and $G_2$? Thanks.

Comment: There are some clue. 
http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbimar/small_groups.pdf

Comment: $G_1 = {\rm AGL}(1,9)$, $G_2 = D_{72}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. I need some time to prove that these two groups satisfy the conditions above. You can post this comment to the answer.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DereHolt I got a smaller example. (In fact, it is the smallest such groups.) They are $G_1=\Bbb{Z}_2\times D_8$ and $G_2=(\Bbb{Z}_2\times D_4)\rtimes \Bbb{Z}_2$ or $G_2=(\Bbb{Z}_2\times Q_8)\rtimes \Bbb{Z}_2$. It is the answer from GAP. I am trying to prove that. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I thought there would be smaller examples, but I tried to produce one that didn't require a computer search.